# Is it possible to create a best fit Linq query from a list of classes?

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have a function which returns the best fit of a class from a collection. I know how to replace the foreach statement using a linq query to get a new list but I would like to know if it is possible to returna single result using a linq statement that would equate to the best fit similar to the code below.

```
private ProductDefaults GetBestFitProductDefault(Product product,IList<ProductDefaults> defaultList, ProductDefaultsTypeEnum type)
    {
        ProductDefaults pdef = null;
        var matches = -1;
        var bestfit = matches;
        foreach (var def in defaultList)
        {
            if(def.DefaultType == type)
            {
                matches = 0;
                if (def.Level1Ref == product.Level1Ref)
                {
                    matches++;
                }
                if (def.Level2Ref == product.Level2Ref)
                {
                    matches++;
                }
                if (def.Level3Ref == product.Level3Ref)
                {
                    matches++;
                }
                if (def.Level4Ref == product.Level4Ref)
                {
                    matches++;
                }
                if (def.Level5Ref == product.Level5Ref)
                {
                    matches++;
                }
                if (def.Level6Ref == product.Level6Ref)
                {
                    matches++;
                }
                if(matches > bestfit)
                {
                    bestfit = matches;
                    pdef = def;
                }
            }
        }
        return pdef;
    }
```

Comment: you can use `LINQ` to get the list with specified `DefaultType`, otherwise I don't see how `LINQ` would help

Comment: Thanks for the reply I was just wondering if it was possible but if not no worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research I have come up with this Linq query to replace the code hopefully this will help someone else who may need a similar solution. The let allows me to create a new column that will calculate the bestfit or number of matches. By ordering the result descending by the bestfit I am certain that the first object will have the highest bestfit value so is the one I need. There could potentially be multiple products with the same bestfit score in this case it would be random which one was chosen but in my case this would be acceptable.

```
private ProductDefaults GetBestFitProductDefault(Product product, IList<ProductDefaults> defaultList, ProductDefaultsTypeEnum type)
    {
        ProductDefaults pdef = null;
        var list =
                    from pd in defaultList
                    let bestfit = pd.Level1Ref == product.Level1Ref ? 1 : 0 +
                                  pd.Level2Ref == product.Level2Ref ? 1 : 0 +
                                  pd.Level3Ref == product.Level3Ref ? 1 : 0 +
                                  pd.Level4Ref == product.Level4Ref ? 1 : 0 +
                                  pd.Level5Ref == product.Level5Ref ? 1 : 0 +
                                  pd.Level6Ref == product.Level6Ref ? 1 : 0
                    where pd.DefaultType == type
                    orderby bestfit descending
                    group pd by bestfit into pdl
                    select new { pdl.Key, best = pdl.ToList() };

        pdef = list.First().best.FirstOrDefault();
        return pdef;
    }
```